# temporarily stopping function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var start = $('#start_img');

start.on('click', function(){
    var piano = $('.piano');
    piano.each(function(index){
        $(this).hide().delay(700 * index).fadeIn(700*index);
        start.off('click');
    })

});
```

You can see that I have used the **start.off('click')** method, to stop the Event Listener from running again once it has been called. But the thing is, I only want the Event listener to be off during the time that the **event is running**. So that it cannot be called again while the event is still running. But once the event has finished, I want it to be 'callable' again. Does anyone know how t do this?

other way of doing this (doesn't work neither). Can anyone help me here. The other one is now clear.

```
var start = $('#start_img');



    start.on('click', function() {
      var q = 0;
      var piano = $('.piano');
      if (q === 1) {
        return; // don't do animations
      }
      else{
        piano.each(function(index) {
        q = 1;
        $(this).hide()
               .delay(700 * index)
               .fadeIn(700 * index, function() {
                    // remove from each instance when animation completes
                    q = 0
                });

      });}

    });
```

Comment: till fadeIn is completede

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle a class on active elements as well and then you can check for that class and not do anything if it exists

```
start.on('click', function() {
  var piano = $('.piano');
  if (piano.hasClass('active')) {
    return; // don't do animations
  }
  piano.each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('active')
           .hide()
           .delay(700 * index)
           .fadeIn(700 * index, function() {
                // remove from each instance when animation completes
                $(this).removeClass('active')
            });

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I was also thinking about another way of doing this, using a variable named q.But it doesn't work. Could you explain to me why? I will edit that example into my initial question.

Comment: because there is more than one element and it would get changed by the very first one while others are still active

Answer (score 0):

For only one object, you could use a global variable for this, in my case, I'll be using `isRunning`:

```
var start = $('#start_img');
var isRunning = false;

start.on('click', function(){
    if (!isRunning){
        isRunning = true;
        var piano = $('.piano');
        piano.each(function(index){
            $(this).hide().delay(700 * index).fadeIn(700*index, function(){
                isRunning = false;
            });
            start.off('click');
        });
    }
});
```

This way your app shouldn't run the code until `isRunning == false`, which should happen after `fadeIn` is completed.

**Syntaxes:**

```
.fadeIn([duration] [,complete]);
.fadeIn(options);
.fadeIn([duration] [,easing] [,complete]);
```

For two or more objects, Charlietfl's answer should work perfectly.

Comment: first one to finish animation will set `isRunning` false...but others will still be running